# I want to put my PC on Hibernate whenever there is a power cut

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

I live in a country where there can be a power cut unexpectedly. So if anyone please tell me how I can configure my PC so whenever there is a power cut my PC goes to hibernate.
My PC's Configurations are
windows 10
HP Z400 Xeon Quad core

I have a ups but it restarts my PC whenever there is a power failure. Maybe fault with my UPS

Comment: is the computer plugged in to the UPS anywhere other than the main plug? If not, then that just means that your UPS is doing a pretty bad job and cuts power to the computer for about a second causing it to hard shutdown and turn back on

Comment: UPSs typically have some outlets that are only protected against surges, and outlets that have battery backup.  If you plugged your computer into the surge-only outlets, that would explain why it is not keeping the system powered.  If you are using the right outlets, the UPS either has an old, dying battery or it is seriously under-rated for your system (or you are trying to keep a bunch of other stuff powered, also) .  The battery typically lasts only about four years, and is usually replaceable.  (cont'd)

Comment: All but the cheapest, smallest UPSs have a communications port to connect it to your computer to monitor conditions.  They usually come with software to do a controlled shutdown.  There is also free, open source software to do that.

Comment: A cheap UPS won't be truly "_uninterruptible_" - when the line dies there will likely be a few cycles (50/60Hz, thus <100ms) where the output actually **is** interrupted. A healthy PSU should be able to ride this out no problems, but a cheap PSU, one with tired caps or one that is under a high load may not be able to do so. This likely explains the resets that you see.

Answer (score 4):

Going into hibernation involves saving the machine's state (e.g. all RAM content) to a hard disk file. This usually will take at least some seconds and cannot be done without power supply. There are some capacitors in the mains adapter, but they're only for *very* short power interruptions.

You could either use a notebook (with an integrated battery pack), or get an uninterruptible power supply ("UPS") - that's kind of an *external* battery pack, which might last for anything from minutes to hours (depending on load and size). Most UPS types then can notify your computer via USB or network, so your machine can go into hibernation, if the battery capacity drops under (say) 15%. When power is restored, the UPS will automatically recharge.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i have a ups but it restarts my pc whenever there is a powercut. maybe fault with my UPS

Comment: Does your UPS have management/monitoring software? Do you have it installed?